# What does |x| in this formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

On page 2 of the following file https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.01528.pdf, the following is presented:

[image]

What does |x| mean in this context?
If is norm 2, |x| it could take decimal values, therefore it confuses me a bit, I assume that it could be the length of the vector (seen from the number of elements of the vector) but the doubt remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is very weird. It normally means the length of the vector $x$. However, $x$ is a vector in a ${\mathbb R}^n$ and the authors mean $n$.

Comment: Yeah very weird, but I think your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely meaning, as per [another topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation#Definition_and_basic_properties), is the number of components in the vector $x$. Indeed, that *must* be what it means, because $i$ runs from $1$ to $|x|$ as thus defined; the sum is just the dot product $w\cdot x$.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the previous page:

> For example, the activation of a single computation unit in a neural network is typically calculated using the dot product (from linear algebra) of an edge weight vector $\bf{w}$ with an input vector $\bf{x}$ plus a scalar bias (threshold): $z({\bf x})=\sum_i^nw_ix_i+b={\bf w}\cdot{\bf x}+b$. Function $z({\bf x})$ is called the unit's *affine function* and is followed by a [rectified linear unit](https://goo.gl/7BXceK), which clips negative values to zero: $\max(0, z({\bf x}))$.
> Such a computational unit is sometimes referred to as an "artificial neuron"...

This indicates that the interpretation as the component count of $\bf x$ is correct.